# Why is it impossible to iterate over all TMs with $n$ states and $k$ symbols that halt after $m$ steps on $\epsilon$?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

Define $\{\sigma(n,k,m,i)\}_{i=1}^{l_m}$ an ordered set of all TMs with $n$ states and $k$ symbols that halt after $m$ steps on $\epsilon$

There are $(2kn)^{kn}$ TMs with $n$ states and $k$ symbols, so $l_m$ is always finite and so is the range of $m$.

If we could iterate over $\sigma$ given $n,k$ for all $m,i$, then we could decide the halting problem:

1. Get $n,k$ from input machine
2. Iterate over $\sigma$ for all $m,i$ and check for each one if $\sigma(n,k,m,i)$ equals the input machine, if they are equal accept.
3. Reject.

This is odd because It seems very feasible to constract $\{\sigma(n,k,m,i)\}_{i=1}^{l_m}$ using elementary combinatorics. Even settling on a (computable) combinatorial formula for $l_m$ for all $m$ given $n,k$ will be enough to solve the haling problem since we will know how many machines are there that halt for each $m$, and we can simulate one step at a time for all the $(2kn)^{kn}$ machines and compare each machine that halts with the input machine until reaching $l_m$ for all $m$ without a correct comparison and reject.

Is there a fact (independent of it contradicting the Halting problem) that makes it clear why there is no computable combinatorial formula for $l_m(n,k)$? or am I missing some detail here?

Comment: To solve the halting problem you would also need to iterate over $m$ (eventually you would find all n-state machines halting on $\epsilon$, but you couldn't know if you get one more by increasing $m$), so I think you could simplify your notation and talk about the set of n-state Turing machines halting on $\epsilon$. It is finite for all $n$, but does not have a simple syntactic characterization, this is exactly why the halting problem is not decidable. The halting function is too complex, a small syntactic change can drastically affect semantics, the "space of algorithms" is not well behaved.

Comment: Additionally, the function which maps $n$ to the number of n-state machines halting on $\epsilon$ is not computable

Comment: Expanding a bit on the previous comments, you essentially argued that the language $H$ associated with the Halting problem is recursively enumerable. However, this is a different property than decidability. The problem with the latter is that for rejecting some input we need to prove that it is _not_ in the language while your procedure can only prove membership.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to iterate over all Turing machines with $n$ states and $k$ symbols that halt after $m$ steps on the empty string.